# Form post in spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

The spring form is as follows:

```
<form:form method="post" action="list.html">

    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="entity"><spring:message code="label.entity"/></form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="entity" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.listmessage"/>"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table> 
</form:form>


<h3>Messages</h3>
<c:if  test="${!empty messageList}">
<table class="data">
<tr>
    <th>Entity</th>
    <th>Available</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${messageList}" var="message">
    <tr>
        <td>${message.entity}</td>
        <td>${message.available}</td>
     </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</c:if>
```

I need help in writing the controller code which will capture the form post;and return the list of messages for display:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String listMessages(String prefixId,Map<String, Object> map) {
    map.put("list",messageService.getMessagesByEntity(prefixId));
    return "redirect:/list";
}
```

The above wouldnt work - but I need help to get the correct adaption.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This

```
<input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.listmessage"/>"/>
```

won't do anything. The form POST will not even include it because it doesn't have a name. Start with

```
<input name="listMessage" type="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.listmessage"/>"/>
```

When the browser sends the request, it will add a parameter like `listMessage=[whatever value is in label.listmessage]`. You can retrieve this request parameter as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String listMessages(@RequestParam(value="listMessage") String listMessage, Model model) {
    // get whatever you need with the request param and put it in the model
    model.addAttribute("messageList",messageService.getMessagesByEntity(listMessage));
    return "redirect:/list";
}
```

The attributes in the model are added to the request attributes and are therefore available in the jsp with `${messageList}`.

Comment: How do I submit and capture the value entered in the entity field?

Comment: @IUnknown I don't know the spring taglib very well. You need to find a way to give the input element a `name` attribute.